# $idl command in terminal does not start IDL

Tags: macos, unix, idl-programming-language

Entering $idl in terminal returns 'command not found'.

'which idl' gives nothing as well.

The default IDL_PATH is:

/Applications/exelis/idl83/lib/bridges:/Applications/exelis/idl83/lib/datatypes:/Applications/exelis/idl83/lib/dicomex:/Applications/exelis/idl83/lib/graphics:/Applications/exelis/idl83/lib/hook:/Applications/exelis/idl83/lib/imsl:/Applications/exelis/idl83/lib/itools/components:/Applications/exelis/idl83/lib/itools/framework:/Applications/exelis/idl83/lib/itools/ui_widgets:/Applications/exelis/idl83/lib/itools:/Applications/exelis/idl83/lib/obsolete:/Applications/exelis/idl83/lib/utilities:/Applications/exelis/idl83/lib/wavelet/data:/Applications/exelis/idl83/lib/wavelet/source:/Applications/exelis/idl83/lib:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/data:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/demo/demodata:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/demo/demoslideshows/slideshowsrc:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/demo/demosrc:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/demo:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/doc/bridges:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/doc/dicom:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/doc/file_io:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/doc/image:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/doc/itools:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/doc/language:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/doc/objects:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/doc/plot:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/doc/sdf:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/doc/shaders:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/doc/signal:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/doc/utilities:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/doc/widgets:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/HP_TIFF:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/imsl:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/misc:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/mjpeg2000:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/ogc/wcs:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/ogc/wms:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/widgets/wexmast:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples/widgets:/Applications/exelis/idl83/examples:/Applications/exelis/idl83/idlde/plugins/com.rsi.idldt_8.3.0/icons

I've done a million things to add to the path to be able to start IDL from the command line but nothing works. I'm stumped. Help Please!

Comment: what does  "echo $idl"  show?  (assuming  "Entering $idl in terminal" means you literally entered $idl

Answer (score 1):

The IDL_PATH is not the system path. Add idl to the system path, i.e., something like:

```
$ export PATH=/Applications/exelis/idl/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Or, source the appropriate idl_setup script in the idl/bin directory, which sets up aliases for idl, idlde, and other relevant tools.